# Pass Model from View To Controller Using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

what is the best way to pass model data from View to Controller using actionLink. actually my action link is download link and i want to pass report model as it contains datatable information.

```
   private void DownloadReport(ReportModel rptModel)
   {
       // want to recieve report model here.
     // to do so.
   }
```

Comment: cant you use ajax post for the same?

Comment: yes can you share any example ?

Answer (score 0):

An `ActionLink` is ultimately just an anchor element.

Instead, use a form with an anchor element that submits the form.

The corresponding controller method would accept your `ReportModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax post method for the same..

For example in your view :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rptModel = {
    val1: "val1",
    ....
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/NameOfController/DownloadReport,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(rptModel),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data.success) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
</script>
```

And this whatever you pass from view you will get in your action method.

Comment: but how would i pass datatable ?